# Crippled battery using Linux with Intel Tigerlake

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, battery

I've just moved to a new laptop with Debian 11.  However, the battery life is terrible (1/5th time compared to running Windows).
It's an Intel Tigerlake CPU (ThinkPad P14s Gen 2), and I've seen [a post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/u7zxa0/psa_for_intel_tiger_lake_dynamic_tuning_laptops/) suggesting that Intel's DTT may be the issue for GNU/Linux.
The fix on the post doesn't appear to have worked for me, namely setting:

```
sudo sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0 # temporarily
```

or creating a file `60-mdapi.conf` in `/etc/sysctl.d/` then containing:

```
dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
```

Approaches like [tlp](https://linrunner.de/tlp/index.html) and [thermald](https://wiki.debian.org/thermald) do not seem to have helped, it's not a thermal issue.
I believe there needs to be some tuning of the kernel to make sure that the Intel DTT is used properly, otherwise the CPU will eat through the battery even when idling.

However, I'm unsure how to do this in Debian, and if the kernel is new enough (5.17.0-1-amd64).

**EDIT 1**

Running `cpupower frequency-info` as suggested by [@mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai) gives the following output:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 4.80 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 1.04 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

I believe this implies that the CPU scaling is working, but I am concerned by the `Unable to call hardware` result.  Perhaps the kernel thinks it is doing scaling, but is not correctly interfacing with the hardware?

**EDIT 2**

It appears that there were missing frequency scaling packages on my system, and they were not configured.  By following the instructions [on this Debian page](https://wiki.debian.org/CpuFrequencyScaling), my laptop is now using battery at the expected rate.

Comment: Are all system resources nearly idle?

Comment: Yes, I've tested leaving the machine running with no heavy applications running.  CPU usage <2% on average, memory usage <10%.  Battery drains from 100% to 0% in around 90mins

Comment: It sounds like Linux is not setting up the CPU to clock down properly. https://wiki.debian.org/CpuFrequencyScaling seems like a start, at the very least I'd look at the output of `sudo cpupower frequency-info`

Comment: I have added this info as an edit to the original post